# The navigation bar of my website does not show on some browsers

Tags: html, css

I have used a pretty standard code to create a navigation bar on my website [www.alexanderpopov.org](http://www.alexanderpopov.org). I am using a css, and it shows nicely on my work computer. The problem is that on many computers/browsers, the navigation bar disappears, and all you see is the different categories in a line, without space and without the black background. I have a very basic knowledge of html and the problem is totally mystifying to me. I paste the script below; very grateful for any advice! Alex

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Alexander Popov — Home</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Back to top button -->
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
<script>
//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 200px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
</script> 
<!-- Main Container -->
<div class="container"> 
  
  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"> <a href="index.html" class="active">Home   </a> <a href="principal.html">Selected Publications   </a> <a href="research.html">Published Research   </a> <a href="working.html">Working Papers   </a> <a href="personal.html">Personal   </a>    <a href="Alex_Popov_CV.pdf">Curriculum Vitae</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a> </div>
    <script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script> 
  </header>
  <!-- Hero Section -->
  <section class="intro">
    <div class="column"> <img src="images/profile.png" alt="" class="profile"> </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Alexander A. Popov</h3>
      <p>PhD, <em>University of Chicago</em> <br>
        Research Adviser, <em>European Central Bank</em><br>
        Research Fellow, <em>CEPR Financial Economics &amp; CEPR Monetary Economics</em></p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Starts Content Section -->
  
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Intro</h3>
    <p>I am a research economist, at the <em>European Central Bank</em> since 2007. </p>
    <p>I am also a <em>CEPR Research Fellow</em>, both in the <em style="">Financial Economics Programme</em> and in the <em>Monetary Economics and Fluctuations Programme</em>.</p>
    <p>My areas of interest are:
    <ul>
      <li>finance, growth, and risk;</li>
      <li>banks and the real economy;</li>
      <li>finance and politics;</li>
      <li>finance and labor.</li>
    </ul>
    </p>
    <p>My work has been published in top journals in both economics and finance, such as <em>American Economic Journal: Macroeconomics, Journal of International Economics</em> (2x), <em>Journal of Development Economics, Journal of Financial Economics, Review of Financial Studies</em> (2x), <em>American Economic Review Papers &amp; Proceedings</em>, and <em>European Economic Review</em>.</p>
    <p>My research papers have been presented in top academic conferences in economics, such as <em>AEA</em> (3x), <em>AFA</em> (2x), <em>Darden International Finance</em> (2x), <em>ECB/CEPR Labor Market Workshop</em> (2x), <em>Econometric Society World Congress, EEA</em> (3x), <em style="">EFA</em> (7x), <em>FIRS</em> (2x), <em>Lenzerheide</em>, <em>RES</em> (3x), <em>SED</em>, <em style="">Utah Finance</em>, and <em>WFA</em> (2x).</p>
    <p>My research has been cited by the <em>Economist, Bloomberg, Financial Times</em>, and <em>Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung</em>, as well as received <em>Best Paper Awards</em> from the <em>Review of Finance</em>, the <em>Australasian Conference on Banking and Finance</em>, and the <em>Cass Business School Emerging Markets Finance Conference</em>.</p>
    <p>I have taught an undergraduate course in <em>econometrics</em> at the <em>University of Chicago</em> and a graduate course in <em>corporate finance theory</em> at <em>Tilburg University</em>.</p>
    <p>In the <em>RePEc</em> ranking, I am ranked in the <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/top/top.person.all10.html"><strong>top 1% in the world in the past 10 years</strong></a>, and in the top 100 in Europe.</p>
    <p>Disclaimer: This is my personal website. The opinions expressed here do not represent the views of the <em>ECB</em> or the <em>Eurosystem</em>.</p>
    <h3>Recent</h3>
    <p><strong>December 2021:</strong> <em>The Economist</em> <a href="https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2021/12/04/how-piecemeal-carbon-pricing-affects-cross-border-lending">featured</a> my recent paper <a href="http://cepr.org/active/publications/discussion_papers/dp.php?dpno=16745">Carbon Taxes and the Geography of Fossil Lending</a> with <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/laevenl/home">Luc Laeven</a> to make the case for a global - as opposed to a piecemeal - carbon tax.</p>
    <p><strong>October 2021:</strong> I joined the <em>Monetary Economics and Fluctuations Program</em> and the <em>Financial Economics Program</em> of the <a href="http://www.cepr.org"><em>CEPR</em></a> as a Research Fellow.</p>
    <p><strong>May 2021:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/oup/rfinst/v34y2021i6p3138-3180..html"><em>Political Cycles in Bank Lending to the Government</em></a> (with <a href="http://www.iwh-halle.de/en/about-the-iwh/people/detail/michael-koetter/">Michael Koetter</a>) was published in the <em>Review of Financial Studies</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>November 2020:</strong> My <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/wly/jmoncb/v52y2020is1p307-311.html">discussion</a> of <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/orkunsaka/">Orkun Saka</a>'s <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/wly/jmoncb/v52y2020is1p273-305.html"><em>Domestic Banks As Lightning Rods? Home Bias and Information during the Eurozone Crisis</em></a> was published in the <em>Journal of Money, Credit, and Banking</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>October 2020:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/jbfina/v120y2020ics0378426620302120.html"><em>Debt Overhang, Global Growth Opportunities, and Investment</em></a> (with <a href="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/research/authors/profiles/francesca-barbiero.en.html">Francesca Barbiero</a> and <a href="http://marcinwolski.org/">Marcin Wolski</a>) was published in the <em>Journal of Banking &amp; Finance</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>December 2019:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/pal/imfecr/v67y2019i4d10.1057_s41308-019-00092-2.html"><em>On the Link Between the Volatility and Skewness of Growth</em></a> (with <a href="http://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/gbekaert/">Geert Bekaert</a>) was published in the <em>IMF Economic Review</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>October 2019:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/aea/aejmac/v11y2019i4p346-79.html"><em>The Invisible Hand of the Government: Moral Suasion During the Sovereign Debt Crisis</em></a> (with <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/stevenongena/">Steven Ongena</a> and <a href="https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/research/researchers/neeltje-van-horen">Neeltje Van Horen</a>) was published in the <em>American Economic Journal: Macroeconomics</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>June 2019:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/eecrev/v115y2019icp25-59.html"><em>Credit Market Competition and the Gender Gap in Labor Force Participation: Evidence from Local Labor Markets</em></a> (with <a href="https://sites.google.com/view/soniazaharia">Sonia Zaharia</a>) was published in the <em>European Economic Review</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>June 2019:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/wly/jmoncb/v51y2019i4p895-928.html"><em>Do SMEs Benefit from Unconventional Monetary Policy and How? Micro-Evidence from the Eurozone</em></a> (with <a href="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/research/authors/profiles/annalisa-ferrando.en.html">Annalisa Ferrando</a> and <a href="http://www.kelley.iu.edu/gudell/">Gregory F. Udell</a>) was published in the <em>Journal of Money, Credit and Banking</em>.</p>
    <p><strong> April 2019:</strong> I joined the <em>Economic Policy Panel</em> for the period 2019-2020.</p>
    <p><strong>February 2019:</strong> I joined the <em>Journal of Banking &amp; Finance</em> as an associate editor.</p>
    <h3>Coming Up</h3>
    <p>I will discuss "Climate Risk and FDI" by Grace Gu and Galina Hale at the <em>NBER’s</em> 45th annual meeting of the <em>International Seminar on Economics</em>, hosted by the <em>Bank of Greece</em> on June 20-21.</p>
    <p>I am co-organizing, with <a href="http://www.ebrd.com/what-we-do/economic-research-and-data/researchers/ralph-de-haas.html">Ralph De Haas</a>, the <em>CEPR/EBRD/ECB Symposium</em> on “Climate change, finance and green growth”. The inaugural event took place virtually on 14-15 June 2021 in Frankfurt, and we had a very strong <a href="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/conferences/html/20210614_cepr_ebrd_ecb_symposium.en.html">program</a>. Stay tuned for the next installment!</p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Footer Section -->
  <footer>
    <div class="button"><a href="mailto:Alexander.Popov@ecb.europa.eu">EMAIL ME</a></div>
    <p align="center"><strong>Tel.: +49(0)6913448428</strong></p>
    <div class="footernav"> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/f/ppo244.html">My RePEc page</a> <a href="https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=j0VnsWIAAAAJ">My Google scholar page</a> <a href="http://voxeu.org/users/alexanderpopov0">My Vox page</a> </div>
    <p align="center"><small>&copy;2022 Alexander Popov. Designed by <a href="https://alphadesigner.com" target="_blank">Alphadesigner</a>.</small></p>
  </footer>
</div>

<!-- Main Container Ends -->



</body>
</html>
```

And here is the css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Google Fonts Import */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2 family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;1,300;1,400;1,600&display=swap');
/* Body */
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 0;
}
/* Links */
a {
  color: #1D7E96;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/* Container */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #F7F3E9;
}
/* Header */
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Content */
.intro {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 1200px 400px;
  background-position: center bottom;
}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {
  .intro {
    background-image: url(../images/bg@3x.jpg);
  }
  .column {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    float: left;
  }
  .intro .column h3 {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .intro .column p {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .intro .column em {
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  .content {
    width: 60%;
    align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .content h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: #D45D35;
    top: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: thin dotted #D45D35;
  }
  .content h4 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .content p {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .content em {
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .content li {
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: inside;
  }
  footer {
    background-color: #E4D9C9;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  footer p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .profile {
    width: 50%;
  }
  /* Mobile */
  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    .intro {
      background-position: center top;
    }
    .content {
      width: 80%;
    }
    .intro .column h3 {
      width: 90%;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .intro .column p {
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .column {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .profile {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  /* Small Tablets */
  @media (min-width: 321px)and (max-width: 767px) {
    .intro {
      background-position: center top;
    }
    .content {
      width: 80%;
    }
    .column {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
    }
    .profile {
      width: 80%;
    }
    .intro .column h3 {
      width: 90%;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .intro .column p {
      width: 90%;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 0px;
    }
  }
  /* Small Desktops */
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1096px) {
    .intro .column p {
      width: 80%;
    }
    .profile {
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
  /*MENUS */
  .footernav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footernav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #1D7E96;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .topnav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0 #000000;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #F7F3E9;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #F7F3E9;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .topnav a:hover {
    color: #83C3E1;
  }
  .topnav a.active {
    color: #83C3E1;
  }
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  /* When the screen is less than 900 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .topnav {
      position: fixed;
      height: auto;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
      display: none;
    }
    .topnav a:first-child {
      margin-left: 42px;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  /* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .topnav.responsive {
      position: fixed;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a.icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  }
  /* Back to top button */
  #myBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0 #000000;
  }
  #myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #1D7E96;
  }
  /*Email Button */
  .button {
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .button a {
    color: #F7F3E9;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .button:hover {
    background-color: #1D7E96;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Comment: Could you please add your css to the post so we can understand what is going on?

Comment: Yes, of course! Sorry about that, should have done it right away. Will add it to the original post,

Comment: You are missing a lot of html code as I cannot see any nav in your html code. Please post the full version as I cannot recreate the problem like this :D

Comment: I now posted the full html code for the index page! I hope I haven't forgotten anything, the index page and the css are now there :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close your `media-query`, it is found at line 51 of your css file.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {
```

Therefor the styling of your navbar and all the other things inside the `media-query` will not display unless the screen matches the query.

I do not know what you want to create with the `media-query` therefor I cannot place it correctly. But when I commented the `media-query` out of your code your css displayed on your website.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Google Fonts Import */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2 family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;1,300;1,400;1,600&display=swap');
/* Body */
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 0;
}
/* Links */
a {
  color: #1D7E96;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/* Container */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #F7F3E9;
}
/* Header */
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Content */
.intro {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 1200px 400px;
  background-position: center bottom;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {   .intro {
background-image: url(../images/bg@3x.jpg);   }   .column {
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 30px;
float: left;   }   .intro .column h3 {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
text-align: left;
line-height: 25px;
font-weight: 600;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
width: 80%;
font-size: 24px;   }   .intro .column p {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
text-align: left;
line-height: 25px;
font-weight: 400;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
width: 80%;
font-size: 16px;   }   .intro .column em {
font-weight: 300;   } }

  .content {
    width: 60%;
    align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .content h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: #D45D35;
    top: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: thin dotted #D45D35;
  }
  .content h4 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .content p {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .content em {
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .content li {
    list-style-type: square;
    list-style-position: inside;
  }
  footer {
    background-color: #E4D9C9;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  footer p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .profile {
    width: 50%;
  }
  /* Mobile */
  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    .intro {
      background-position: center top;
    }
    .content {
      width: 80%;
    }
    .intro .column h3 {
      width: 90%;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .intro .column p {
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .column {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .profile {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  /* Small Tablets */
  @media (min-width: 321px)and (max-width: 767px) {
        .intro {
        background-position: center top;
        }
        .content {
        width: 80%;
        }
        .column {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        }
        .profile {
        width: 80%;
        }
        .intro .column h3 {
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 0px;
        }
        .intro .column p {
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 0px;
        }
  }
  /* Small Desktops */
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1096px) {
        .intro .column p {
        width: 80%;
        }
        .profile {
        width: 80%;
        }
  }
  /*MENUS */
  .footernav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footernav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #1D7E96;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .topnav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px 0 #000000;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #F7F3E9;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #F7F3E9;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .topnav a:hover {
    color: #83C3E1;
  }
  .topnav a.active {
    color: #83C3E1;
  }
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  /* When the screen is less than 900 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .topnav {
      position: fixed;
      height: auto;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
      display: none;
    }
    .topnav a:first-child {
      margin-left: 42px;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  /* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .topnav.responsive {
      position: fixed;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a.icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  }
  /* Back to top button */
  #myBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0 #000000;
  }
  #myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #1D7E96;
  }
  /*Email Button */
  .button {
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .button a {
    color: #F7F3E9;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .button:hover {
    background-color: #1D7E96;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Alexander Popov — Home</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Back to top button -->
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
<script>
//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 200px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
</script> 
<!-- Main Container -->
<div class="container"> 
  
  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"> <a href="index.html" class="active">Home   </a> <a href="principal.html">Selected Publications   </a> <a href="research.html">Published Research   </a> <a href="working.html">Working Papers   </a> <a href="personal.html">Personal   </a>    <a href="Alex_Popov_CV.pdf">Curriculum Vitae</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a> </div>
    <script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script> 
  </header>
  <!-- Hero Section -->
  <section class="intro">
    <div class="column"> <img src="images/profile.png" alt="" class="profile"> </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Alexander A. Popov</h3>
      <p>PhD, <em>University of Chicago</em> <br>
        Research Adviser, <em>European Central Bank</em><br>
        Research Fellow, <em>CEPR Financial Economics &amp; CEPR Monetary Economics</em></p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Starts Content Section -->
  
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Intro</h3>
    <p>I am a research economist, at the <em>European Central Bank</em> since 2007. </p>
    <p>I am also a <em>CEPR Research Fellow</em>, both in the <em style="">Financial Economics Programme</em> and in the <em>Monetary Economics and Fluctuations Programme</em>.</p>
    <p>My areas of interest are:
    <ul>
      <li>finance, growth, and risk;</li>
      <li>banks and the real economy;</li>
      <li>finance and politics;</li>
      <li>finance and labor.</li>
    </ul>
    </p>
    <p>My work has been published in top journals in both economics and finance, such as <em>American Economic Journal: Macroeconomics, Journal of International Economics</em> (2x), <em>Journal of Development Economics, Journal of Financial Economics, Review of Financial Studies</em> (2x), <em>American Economic Review Papers &amp; Proceedings</em>, and <em>European Economic Review</em>.</p>
    <p>My research papers have been presented in top academic conferences in economics, such as <em>AEA</em> (3x), <em>AFA</em> (2x), <em>Darden International Finance</em> (2x), <em>ECB/CEPR Labor Market Workshop</em> (2x), <em>Econometric Society World Congress, EEA</em> (3x), <em style="">EFA</em> (7x), <em>FIRS</em> (2x), <em>Lenzerheide</em>, <em>RES</em> (3x), <em>SED</em>, <em style="">Utah Finance</em>, and <em>WFA</em> (2x).</p>
    <p>My research has been cited by the <em>Economist, Bloomberg, Financial Times</em>, and <em>Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung</em>, as well as received <em>Best Paper Awards</em> from the <em>Review of Finance</em>, the <em>Australasian Conference on Banking and Finance</em>, and the <em>Cass Business School Emerging Markets Finance Conference</em>.</p>
    <p>I have taught an undergraduate course in <em>econometrics</em> at the <em>University of Chicago</em> and a graduate course in <em>corporate finance theory</em> at <em>Tilburg University</em>.</p>
    <p>In the <em>RePEc</em> ranking, I am ranked in the <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/top/top.person.all10.html"><strong>top 1% in the world in the past 10 years</strong></a>, and in the top 100 in Europe.</p>
    <p>Disclaimer: This is my personal website. The opinions expressed here do not represent the views of the <em>ECB</em> or the <em>Eurosystem</em>.</p>
    <h3>Recent</h3>
    <p><strong>December 2021:</strong> <em>The Economist</em> <a href="https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2021/12/04/how-piecemeal-carbon-pricing-affects-cross-border-lending">featured</a> my recent paper <a href="http://cepr.org/active/publications/discussion_papers/dp.php?dpno=16745">Carbon Taxes and the Geography of Fossil Lending</a> with <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/laevenl/home">Luc Laeven</a> to make the case for a global - as opposed to a piecemeal - carbon tax.</p>
    <p><strong>October 2021:</strong> I joined the <em>Monetary Economics and Fluctuations Program</em> and the <em>Financial Economics Program</em> of the <a href="http://www.cepr.org"><em>CEPR</em></a> as a Research Fellow.</p>
    <p><strong>May 2021:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/oup/rfinst/v34y2021i6p3138-3180..html"><em>Political Cycles in Bank Lending to the Government</em></a> (with <a href="http://www.iwh-halle.de/en/about-the-iwh/people/detail/michael-koetter/">Michael Koetter</a>) was published in the <em>Review of Financial Studies</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>November 2020:</strong> My <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/wly/jmoncb/v52y2020is1p307-311.html">discussion</a> of <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/orkunsaka/">Orkun Saka</a>'s <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/wly/jmoncb/v52y2020is1p273-305.html"><em>Domestic Banks As Lightning Rods? Home Bias and Information during the Eurozone Crisis</em></a> was published in the <em>Journal of Money, Credit, and Banking</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>October 2020:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/jbfina/v120y2020ics0378426620302120.html"><em>Debt Overhang, Global Growth Opportunities, and Investment</em></a> (with <a href="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/research/authors/profiles/francesca-barbiero.en.html">Francesca Barbiero</a> and <a href="http://marcinwolski.org/">Marcin Wolski</a>) was published in the <em>Journal of Banking &amp; Finance</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>December 2019:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/pal/imfecr/v67y2019i4d10.1057_s41308-019-00092-2.html"><em>On the Link Between the Volatility and Skewness of Growth</em></a> (with <a href="http://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/gbekaert/">Geert Bekaert</a>) was published in the <em>IMF Economic Review</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>October 2019:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/aea/aejmac/v11y2019i4p346-79.html"><em>The Invisible Hand of the Government: Moral Suasion During the Sovereign Debt Crisis</em></a> (with <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/stevenongena/">Steven Ongena</a> and <a href="https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/research/researchers/neeltje-van-horen">Neeltje Van Horen</a>) was published in the <em>American Economic Journal: Macroeconomics</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>June 2019:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/eecrev/v115y2019icp25-59.html"><em>Credit Market Competition and the Gender Gap in Labor Force Participation: Evidence from Local Labor Markets</em></a> (with <a href="https://sites.google.com/view/soniazaharia">Sonia Zaharia</a>) was published in the <em>European Economic Review</em>.</p>
    <p><strong>June 2019:</strong> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/a/wly/jmoncb/v51y2019i4p895-928.html"><em>Do SMEs Benefit from Unconventional Monetary Policy and How? Micro-Evidence from the Eurozone</em></a> (with <a href="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/research/authors/profiles/annalisa-ferrando.en.html">Annalisa Ferrando</a> and <a href="http://www.kelley.iu.edu/gudell/">Gregory F. Udell</a>) was published in the <em>Journal of Money, Credit and Banking</em>.</p>
    <p><strong> April 2019:</strong> I joined the <em>Economic Policy Panel</em> for the period 2019-2020.</p>
    <p><strong>February 2019:</strong> I joined the <em>Journal of Banking &amp; Finance</em> as an associate editor.</p>
    <h3>Coming Up</h3>
    <p>I will discuss "Climate Risk and FDI" by Grace Gu and Galina Hale at the <em>NBER’s</em> 45th annual meeting of the <em>International Seminar on Economics</em>, hosted by the <em>Bank of Greece</em> on June 20-21.</p>
    <p>I am co-organizing, with <a href="http://www.ebrd.com/what-we-do/economic-research-and-data/researchers/ralph-de-haas.html">Ralph De Haas</a>, the <em>CEPR/EBRD/ECB Symposium</em> on “Climate change, finance and green growth”. The inaugural event took place virtually on 14-15 June 2021 in Frankfurt, and we had a very strong <a href="https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/conferences/html/20210614_cepr_ebrd_ecb_symposium.en.html">program</a>. Stay tuned for the next installment!</p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Footer Section -->
  <footer>
    <div class="button"><a href="mailto:Alexander.Popov@ecb.europa.eu">EMAIL ME</a></div>
    <p align="center"><strong>Tel.: +49(0)6913448428</strong></p>
    <div class="footernav"> <a href="https://ideas.repec.org/f/ppo244.html">My RePEc page</a> <a href="https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=j0VnsWIAAAAJ">My Google scholar page</a> <a href="http://voxeu.org/users/alexanderpopov0">My Vox page</a> </div>
    <p align="center"><small>&copy;2022 Alexander Popov. Designed by <a href="https://alphadesigner.com" target="_blank">Alphadesigner</a>.</small></p>
  </footer>
</div>

<!-- Main Container Ends -->



</body>
</html>
```

[More information about media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: That worked!!! The nav bar is back. Amazingly useful, thank you :) Still another problem persists - the text is left aligned and the photo is too large and in the center of the page; according to the design (which I see on my work computer), there should be space to the left of the text, and the photo should be a small one in the top left corner... Any ideas? And thank you so much once again!!!

Comment: No problem!

You want to play around with the `.intro` styling to fix this, probally because of the `media-query` again.

Please accept my answer at the top left of my answer if this has answered your question.